# How to stop Mongodb .NET driver throwing System.FormatException?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDb .NET Driver System.FormatException / DecoderFallbackException

> An error occurred while deserializing the description property
>   of class KerbToolsService.Models.promotion:
>   Unable to translate bytes [ED][A0] at index 136 from
>   specified code page to Unicode.

A .NET web API app I wrote to monitor the status of our MongoDB / Node.js based system started throwing a DecoderFallbackException.

Here’s a stack trace

```
System.FormatException occurred
  HResult=-2146233033
Message=An error occurred while deserializing the description property of class KerbToolsService.Models.promotion: Unable to translate bytes [ED][A0] at index 136 from specified code page to Unicode.
 Source=MongoDB.Bson

StackTrace:
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
InnerException: System.Text.DecoderFallbackException
   HResult=-2147024809
   Message=Unable to translate bytes [ED][A0] at index 136 from specified code page to Unicode.
   Source=mscorlib
   Index=136
   StackTrace:
        at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
        at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
        at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes)
        at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32 count, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
        at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding)
        at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
        at MongoDB.Bson.IO.Utf8Helper.DecodeUtf8String(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count, UTF8Encoding encoding)
        at MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferStream.ReadString(UTF8Encoding encoding)
        at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBinaryReader.ReadString()
        at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.StringSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SealedClassSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
        at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
```

So far I know that a character `U+D83D` that encoded to `ED A0 BD` in bson is in a document in the database, and is causing .NET UTF8Encoding to throw a DecoderFallbackException. Other code (the MongoLab UI and our Node.js based application) replaces it with a `?` but it kills the query in the .NET driver.

I'd like to get the .NET Mongo driver to behave the same as others and not blow up if it sees invalid UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the ReadEncoding property on the MongoClient in this way:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings() 
{ 
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("<serveraddress>", 27017),
    ReadEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false, false)
});
```

(Edited: as said by @Craig Wilson, settings are readonly after constructor)

The second parameter of UTF8Encoding is "throwOnInvalidBytes":

> **true** to specify that an exception be thrown when an invalid encoding is detected; otherwise, **false**

Source: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-996 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/302sbf78(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you might need to construct the settings and pass them into the ctor. I think client.Settings is readonly at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was wondering why the encoding object was passed down the mongo stack.  Yes, the changing the settings throws: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' MongoClientSettings is frozen. I'll try creating the settings first.

Comment: Solved:  I'll edit the answer with details.  Thanks Stefano & @craig